# Updating a (sadly already distributed) sandboxed OSX application using sparkle

Tags: macos, sandbox, sparkle

In a burst of non-thinking enthusiasm I sandboxed then sparkle-updated my app. Since the app only has read/write access to user selected files (and the music directory) I can't now update my own binary. Oops.

This has been extensively debated with Andy Matuschak over the last year or so (https://github.com/sparkle-project/Sparkle/pull/165) but while the proposed solutions are 'nearly good enough', no light has been shed on the problem of having already distributed a non-sandboxed app.

Oh, and it appears it might be relevant that I've been using the 'disk image' method of sparkle distribution.

The only solution AT ALL that I can think of is to release a sparkle update that *just* presents a message to the users telling them to manually download. Does anyone have any better ideas?

-Dave

Answer (score 2):

Andy Matuschak seems to indicate that Sparkle can actually handle 'download only' gracefully for you. In his own words, just leave the `<enclosure>` out of your `<item>` and add a `<sparkle:version>2.0</sparkle:version>` element as a child of the `<item>`.

Read his comment here: https://github.com/sparkle-project/Sparkle/issues/227#issuecomment-13192723

Just like Fermat before him, he left out one piece of information. But unlike the theorem, we have access to Sparkle source code, in particular `SUAppcastItem.m`. Thanks to the code, I figured out the missing piece was a `<link>` tag. Here is an example appcast:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:sparkle="http://www.andymatuschak.org/xml-namespaces/sparkle"  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
   <channel>
      <title>FooBar</title>
      <link>http://foobar.com/appcast.xml</link>
      <description>Most recent changes with links to updates.</description>
      <language>en</language>
        <item>
            <title>FooBar 2.0</title>
            <sparkle:releaseNotesLink>http://foobar.com/release-notes-special.html</sparkle:releaseNotesLink>
            <sparkle:minimumSystemVersion>10.9.0</sparkle:minimumSystemVersion>
            <pubDate>2014-04-14T18:40:44+02:00</pubDate>
            <sparkle:version>2013</sparkle:version>
            <sparkle:shortVersionString>2.0</sparkle:shortVersionString>
            <link>http://foobar.com/release-notes-special.html</link>
        </item>
   </channel>
</rss>
```

In the sandbox app that receives that appcast and cannot be updated otherwise, the 'Install Update' is gone, and in its place is a 'Learn More' button that will bring the user to the URL in that `<link>`. This is a good place to have instructions for the download.

In the next version of your app, you could then use a different URL for the appcast, so that the above appcast only applies to older versions (assuming you fixed things and now use the non-official XPC trick with Sparkle).

Comment: We're currently in the process of merging sandboxing support into Sparkle, see https://github.com/sparkle-project/Sparkle/issues/363 for more info.